# How to send byte to USB to parallel port to control LED?

Tags: linux, c

I have an USB to 25-pin parallel port cable. I connected it to laptop and get a port at /dev/usb/lp0, if I connect pin1/pin25 of parallel port with +/- LED it lights.

Now I move +pin of LED to pin 2 of parallel port, and try to send byte to port , it should light up but it doesn't.

I use the command `outb(0xff,port)` where port is `0x378`.  What am I missing here?

This is my complete program:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/io.h>
void main(void){
    int port=0x378;
    outb(0xff,port);
    outb(0x01,port+2);
    sleep(1);
    outb(0x00,port+2);
    printf("‌​End");
}
```

I also checked it with `port=0x3bc` but did not work. I even checked strobe pin 1 by connecting + of LED, it always lights but does not go low. Is there any problem with port address?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port and use one of the other pins, maybe follow the i/o port howto mentioned there.

Comment: I have just tried, other data pins like pin5 and 6(data4, data6) but LED did not light. this is my code: int port=0x378; outb(0xff,port);sleep(1); printf("End"); I get text "End" at console but LED does not light even though I change + pin of LED. which pin should I try? and how? please give some hints, thanks

Comment: Have you used a GND pin for each data pin? Usually you write 1 data byte, then you set the strobe signal. It's been some time since I used the parallel port. Later this evening I can send you an example program to control the port (in about 8 hours from now).

Comment: Ok thanks, I use only two pins pin25 at GND and connect - of LED with it. second pin I check any of data pins (from pin2 to pin9) and run the above code. Can you please tell me how can I set the stobe signal? thanks

Comment: What happens if you write to `/dev/usb/lp0`?

Comment: If you need USB to GPIO, there are far better ways to get it than emulating a parallel port. [Googling "usb gpio"](http://www.google.com/search?q=usb+gpio) is a good start. All the standard development boards like the Arduino, Raspberry Pi, Beagle Bone, etc. also give you ways to do this, though that requires writing some code for the development board to bridge the GPIO to the USB side.

Comment: Follow http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IO-Port-Programming.html - the control port (base+2) bit 0 sets strobe.

Comment: for /dev/usb/lp0 I use command line command like $echo $'\xFF' > /dev/usb/lp0 I observed that it does something but does not light up the LED. When I connect LED with pin2 and 25 as + and -. I can see a very little light in side the LED in the beginning but when I run above command that very tiny light disappears but LED does not glow high like it does when I connect it with strobe pin. Also I can only execute above command only two times. Third and later times I thing command does not work while it seems halted. Any idea please?

Comment: Hi ott, now my code looks like this: int port=0x378; outb(0x00,port+2); outb(0xff,port);sleep(1); printf("End"); It compiles and runs but does not glow LED. I also tried by moving outb(0x00,port+2) down to other outb() but did not give the required result :-(

Comment: Try: outb(0xff,port); outb(0x01,port+2);sleep(1);outb(0x00,port+2);

Comment: #include<stdlib.h>#include<stdio.h>#include<sys/io.h>void main(void){int port=0x378;outb(0xff,port);outb(0x01,port+2);sleep(1);outb(0x00,port+2);printf("End");} this is my complete program, I also checked it with port=0x3bc but did not work. Even I checked strobe pin 1 by connecting + of LED, it alsways lights but does not go low. Is there any problem with port address?

Comment: Hey Ott, can you please send me the program to control the port? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Port `0x378` is the I/O location where the old ISA parallel port lives.  The USB-attached parallel port would not show up there.  It couldn't.  I really don't know too much about the low-level details of how talking to the OHCI/UHCI/EHCI/xHCI works, but I know everything you do has to go through the USB host controller.  So on the lowest level you need to query the USB bus, find your device's VID, open some sort of communication with it, set a communication mode and then send/receive bytes one at a time.

Try writing your data directly to `/dev/usb/lp0` and see what happens.  You may need to do something to change the ECP mode first, possibly some special `ioctl`.  You may need to dig into the source code for this driver to really find out what to do.

Failing that, see if you can get a dock for your laptop.  If your laptop happens to be a business class laptop I've noticed the docks available usually have the legacy ports on them, and they work as you're trying to use them here.

Comment: for /dev/usb/lp0 I use command line command like $echo $'\xFF' > /dev/usb/lp0 I observed that it does something but does not light up the LED. When I connect LED with pin2 and 25 as + and -. I can see a very little light in side the LED in the beginning but when I run above command that very tiny light disappears but LED does not glow high like it does when I connect it with strobe pin. Also I can only execute above command only two times. Third and later times I thing command does not work while it seems halted. Any idea please?